# Error Code: 1422. Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, stored-functions, mysql-error

Everywhere I look it seems MySQL stored procedures can do transactions. Yet when I declare my stored function

```sql
create function test( a int )
returns int
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION ;
  update t set col='some value' where id=a ;
  COMMIT ;
  return 0 ;
END //
```

I get

> Error Code: 1422. Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually you are not allowed transactions inside stored *functions*.  You are allowed transactions inside stored ***procedures*** only.

```
create procedure test( a int )
MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION ;
  update t set col='some value' where id=a ;
  COMMIT ;
END //
```

To return values from the SP, use output parameters or use the result set from the last select statement in the SP.

Comment: Also worth noting is that if you call the procedure from within a trigger, you will still be rewarded with an '_Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger_' error.  Frustrating.

Comment: hey, this is a bit old, but I'm running into this problem right now. Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot use [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) in a [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) while we can in a [procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html).

So, I got the same error below:

> ERROR 1422 (HY000): Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.

Because I used transaction with `START TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT;` in a function as shown below:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
    -- Statements
  COMMIT;
END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

But, I could use transaction with `START TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT;` in a procedure without error as shown below:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc()
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
    -- Statements
  COMMIT;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

In addition, using `BEGIN;` instead of `START TRANSACTION;` in a procedure gets the error below:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc()
BEGIN
  -- START TRANSACTION;
  BEGIN; -- Here
    -- Statements
  COMMIT;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';